# How to avoid nested switch constructions?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, dynamic, repository-pattern

For example, I have two classes

```
 public class A
 {
     public Guid Id { get; set;}
     public string Type { get; set; }
     public string State { get; set; }
     public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
 }

 public class B 
 {
     public Guid Id { get; set; }
     public string Type { get; set; }
     public string State { get; set; }
     public string AnotherProperty { get; set; }
 }
```

Each class has its own repository

```
 public class RepA
 {
     public void Add(A entity)
     {
         // some specific logic here
     }

     public void Delete(A entity)
     {
         // some specific logic here
     }
 }

 public class RepB
 {
     public void Add(B entity)
     {
         // some specific logic here
     }

     public void Delete(B entity)
     {
         // some specific logic here
     }
 }
```

I need to implement a method for saving list of entities with dynamic types. I want to avoid using nested "switch" constructions (as listed below) so as I have more than 2 types and more than 2 states and code becomes to look messy.

```
 private readonly RepA _repA = new RepA();
 private readonly RepB _repB = new RepB();

 public void SaveChanges(List<dynamic> entities)
 {
      foreach (var entity in entities)
      {
           switch (entity.Type)
           {
                case "A": 
                     var a = entity as A;
                     switch (entity.State)
                     {
                          case "Added":
                               _repA.Add(a);
                               break;
                          case "Deleted":
                               _repA.Delete(a);
                               break;
                     }
                     break;
                 case "B":
                     var b = entity as B;
                     switch (entity.State)
                     {
                          case "Added":
                               _repB.Add(b);
                               break;
                          case "Deleted":
                               _repB.Delete(b);
                               break;
                     }
                     break;
          }
      }
 }
```

Could you suggest any other solutions?
I thought about interfaces for base class and base repository. But in this case when and how should I initialize _repo which is depending on entity type?

```
 private IBaseRep _repo;

 public void SaveChanges(List<dynamic> entities)
 {
      foreach (var entity in entities)
      {
           switch (entity.State)
           {
               case "Added":
                   _repo.Add(entity)
                   break;
               case "Deleted":
                   _repo.Delete(entity)
                   break;
           }
      }
 }
```

Comment: Is `case "Deleted": _repB.Add(b);` a mistake ? You meant `_repB.Delete(b);` ?

Comment: First off why that needs to be a `List<dynamic>`? There are other better options like interface and abstract classes.

Comment: It depends on what A and B are in domain context? Are they related or can participate in inheritance? I guess yes, looking at their members. Please confirm.

Comment: Also repositories should not be defined per entity, but an aggregate root. You could have a single repository (perhaps Generic one) to do Add/Delete operations.

Comment: @OrelEraki, yes, it's a mistake. Fixed it

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, actually an input argument for SaveChanges method has JObject type. After deserialization I get a List <dynamic>

Comment: @nikhilvartak, A and B are not related but I think they can participate in inheritance. And in current project there had already been accessors per entity so it was decided to define repositories also per entities. Repositories contain not only Add/Delete operations but a lot of other business logic methods. So one repository would contain thousands of code lines after joining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your entity classes `A` and `B` are defying DRY principle. How about below? The one issue I can think of is multiple enumeration of entities collection but I'm not sure how big your collection is to know if this is truly an issue or not.

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}

public class A : Entity
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

public class B : Entity
{
    public string AnotherProperty { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Rep<T> where T : Entity
{
    public abstract void Add(T entity);
    public abstract void Delete(T entity);
    public virtual void SaveChanges(IEnumerable<T> entities)
    {
        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            switch (entity.State)
            {
                case "Added":
                    Add(entity);
                    break;
                case "Deleted":
                    Delete(entity);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new InvalidOperationException($"Invalid entity state {entity.State}");
            }
        }
    }
}

public class RepA : Rep<A>
{
    public override void Add(A entity)
    {
        // some specific logic here
    }

    public override void Delete(A entity)
    {
        // some specific logic here
    }
}

public class RepB : Rep<B>
{
    public override void Add(B entity)
    {
        // some specific logic here
    }

    public override void Delete(B entity)
    {
        // some specific logic here
    }
}

public class Program
{
    private static readonly RepA _repA = new RepA();
    private static readonly RepB _repB = new RepB();

    public static void Main()
    {
        var entities = new List<Entity>();

        // fill the list here

        _repA.SaveChanges(entities.OfType<A>());
        _repB.SaveChanges(entities.OfType<B>());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
What about SomeProperty from class A and AnotherProperty from class B, won't they be missed in this case?

Comment: No. The properties rightfully belong to each class. Also, you can implement logic depending on `SomeProperty` and `AnotherProperty` in classes `RepA` and `RepB`'s `Add()` and `Delete()` methods.

Comment: Thank you. I will try it

Answer (score 1):

The [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) is specifically intended for dealing with homogeneous lists.